# JavaScript: Stop SetInterval if no response

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I'm using an alternate code to `navigator.OnLine` to check for network connection. It works, however, I'm having some issues with it.

If I'm connected/disconnected to the network inside the intranet (corporate network) , then I have no issues whatsoever. However, if I'm home and I'm connected to my home network, but not connected to the corporate intranet using a VPN connection, then the window will freeze for 10 second intervals. I think it's because there's internet connection, but the server is unreachable because I'm disconnected from the intranet.

Here's the code:

```
function serverReachable() {
  // IE vs. standard XHR creation
  var x = new ( window.ActiveXObject || XMLHttpRequest )( "Microsoft.XMLHTTP" ),
      s;
  x.open(
    // requesting the headers is faster, and just enough
    "HEAD",
    // append a random string to the current hostname,
    // to make sure we're not hitting the cache
    "http://16.24.163.33" + window.location.hostname + "/?rand=" + Math.random(),
    // make a synchronous request
    false
  );
  try {
    x.send();
    s = x.status;
    // Make sure the server is reachable
    return ( s >= 200 && s < 300 || s === 304 );
  // catch network & other problems
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

What I would like to do with your help, is to cancel a request that takes more than one second. So if I'm trying to reach 16.24.163.33 from home, and no response was received after 1 (!) second, then cancel the request, and retry this whole code again in two minutes.

```
setInterval(function () {
    if (serverReachable()) {
        if (timeout === null) {
    var changeIt = document.getElementById('change')
    changeIt.style.visibility = 'hidden';
           timeout = setInterval("refreshIframe()",25000);
        }
    } else {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = null;
    var changeIt = document.getElementById('change')
    changeIt.style.visibility = 'visible';
       }
}, 900);
```

Comment: Do you really need to make a synchronous request? If so then by definition no other JS is going to execute until the Ajax is done. Where is the `setInterval` mentioned in your question title?

Comment: That's right, you're better off with using the `readStateChange` event handler to evaluate the status of an _async_ request.

Comment: Otherwise what you're trying to do is easily achieved with `setTimeout` / `clearTimeout` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout)